# HTACCESS 301 redirect issue with strange url variables

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

google webmaster tool is notifying me a 404 error about the following url: 
http://www.giobby.com/&force=1
I added the following rule to htaccess file, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&force=1
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.giobby.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Can someone suggest me the correct rules?

Comment: If that's not a typo, I'd expect it should be `?force=1` rather than `&force=1`

Comment: probably should be, but unfortunately google highlight  me exactly this URL http://www.giobby.com/&force=1 . I don't know where he found it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just:

```
RewriteRule ^&force= / [L,NC,R=301]
```